# Proportional representation and ratios

Tags: arrays, sqf

I need to generate a list of numbers to put into an array. These number of times that they occur in the list is based on how important a certain property is.

E.g.

```
// importance ranges from 0 (no importance) to 5 (utmost importance)
maxNumbersInArray = 10;

propAImportance = 5; --> will put 1 into the array
propBImportance = 3; --> will put 2 into the array
propCImportance = 2; --> will put 3 into the array

// Output will be
array = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
```

How can i create a list where the importance of a value means that value is added to an array a greater number of times, or more specifically, how to calculate how ofter a value will be added into an array based on a properties importance

First ideas: (language SQF scripting)

```
_max = 10;

_weight1 = 3;
_weight2 = 2;
_weight3 = 0;
_weight4 = 1;

_weights = [_weight1,_weight2,_weight3,_weight4];

_arr = [];

for "_i" from 0 to (_max - 1) do {
   {
      while {_i <= _x} do {
      _arr set [(count _arr),_forEachIndex];
   } forEach _weights;
};

_arr; // Output
```

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: just needs to be the generic mathematics. language does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the algorithm to use:

```
_index = [];
_max = 10;
_weights = [5,2,1,1];
_count = 0;
_countWeight = 0;
while {(count _index ) < _max } do {
   if (_count >=  (count _weights)) then {_count = 0};
   _weight = _weights select _count;
   _countWeight = _countWeight + 1;
   if (_countWeight > _weight) then {
      _countWeight = 0;
      _count = _count + 1;
   } else {
      _index set [(count _index ),_count];
   };
};
```